# Parse XML File with R Get into data frame

Tags: r, xml, xml-parsing, rbind

XML Data

```
<HealthData locale="en_US">
 <ExportDate value="2016-06-02 14:05:23 -0400"/>
 <Me HKCharacteristicTypeIdentifierDateOfBirth="" HKCharacteristicTypeIdentifierBiologicalSex="HKBiologicalSexNotSet" HKCharacteristicTypeIdentifierBloodType="HKBloodTypeNotSet" HKCharacteristicTypeIdentifierFitzpatrickSkinType="HKFitzpatrickSkinTypeNotSet"/>
 <Record type="HKQuantityTypeIdentifierStepCount" sourceName="Ryan Praskievicz iPhone" unit="count" creationDate="2014-10-02 08:30:17 -0400" startDate="2014-09-24 15:07:06 -0400" endDate="2014-09-24 15:07:11 -0400" value="7"/>
 <Record type="HKQuantityTypeIdentifierStepCount" sourceName="Ryan Praskievicz iPhone" unit="count" creationDate="2014-10-02 08:30:17 -0400" startDate="2014-09-24 15:12:13 -0400" endDate="2014-09-24 15:12:18 -0400" value="15"/>
 <Record type="HKQuantityTypeIdentifierStepCount" sourceName="Ryan Praskievicz iPhone" unit="count" creationDate="2014-10-02 08:30:17 -0400" startDate="2014-09-24 15:17:16 -0400" endDate="2014-09-24 15:17:21 -0400" value="20"/>
</HealthData>
```

R Code

```
> library(XML)
> doc="\\pathtoXMLfile"
> list <-xpathApply(doc, "//HealthData/Record", xmlAttrs)
> df <- do.call(rbind.data.frame, list)
> str(df)
```

I am trying to take the XML data sample shown above and load it into a data frame in R with the name of each Record i.e. Type, sourceName, unit, endDate, value as the column header and each Record value i.e count, 2014-09-24 15:07:11 -0400, 7 as the values for each row in the data frame.

When `df <- do.call(rbind.data.frame, list)` this get's close, but it also looks like it binds all the values for the column headers too. If you `View(df)` or `str(df)` you'll see what I mean. How do I use the Record variable names as the column header names?

Thanks,
Ryan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider `xpathSApply()` to retrieve the attributes, and then transpose with `t()` the resulting list into dataframe:

```
library(XML)

xmlstr <- '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
            <HealthData locale="en_US">
              <ExportDate value="2016-06-02 14:05:23 -0400"/>
              <Me HKCharacteristicTypeIdentifierDateOfBirth="" HKCharacteristicTypeIdentifierBiologicalSex="HKBiologicalSexNotSet" HKCharacteristicTypeIdentifierBloodType="HKBloodTypeNotSet" HKCharacteristicTypeIdentifierFitzpatrickSkinType="HKFitzpatrickSkinTypeNotSet"/>
              <Record type="HKQuantityTypeIdentifierStepCount" sourceName="Ryan Praskievicz iPhone" unit="count" creationDate="2014-10-02 08:30:17 -0400" startDate="2014-09-24 15:07:06 -0400" endDate="2014-09-24 15:07:11 -0400" value="7"/>
              <Record type="HKQuantityTypeIdentifierStepCount" sourceName="Ryan Praskievicz iPhone" unit="count" creationDate="2014-10-02 08:30:17 -0400" startDate="2014-09-24 15:12:13 -0400" endDate="2014-09-24 15:12:18 -0400" value="15"/>
              <Record type="HKQuantityTypeIdentifierStepCount" sourceName="Ryan Praskievicz iPhone" unit="count" creationDate="2014-10-02 08:30:17 -0400" startDate="2014-09-24 15:17:16 -0400" endDate="2014-09-24 15:17:21 -0400" value="20"/>
            </HealthData>'

xml <- xmlParse(xmlstr)

recordAttribs <- xpathSApply(doc=xml, path="//HealthData/Record",  xmlAttrs)
df <- data.frame(t(recordAttribs))
df

#                                type              sourceName  unit
# 1 HKQuantityTypeIdentifierStepCount Ryan Praskievicz iPhone count
# 2 HKQuantityTypeIdentifierStepCount Ryan Praskievicz iPhone count
# 3 HKQuantityTypeIdentifierStepCount Ryan Praskievicz iPhone count
#                creationDate                 startDate                   endDate
# 1 2014-10-02 08:30:17 -0400 2014-09-24 15:07:06 -0400 2014-09-24 15:07:11 -0400
# 2 2014-10-02 08:30:17 -0400 2014-09-24 15:12:13 -0400 2014-09-24 15:12:18 -0400
# 3 2014-10-02 08:30:17 -0400 2014-09-24 15:17:16 -0400 2014-09-24 15:17:21 -0400
#   value
# 1     7
# 2    15
# 3    20
```

---

In case of attributes that appear in some and not others, consider matching against a pre-determined list of names and iteratively fill in `NAs`. Below are two versions using `sapply()` with `for` loop and a second list argument:

```
recordnames <- c("type", "unit", "sourceName", "device", "sourceVersion", 
                 "creationDate", "startDate", "endDate", "value")

# FOR LOOP VERSION
recordAttribs <- sapply(recordAttribs, function(i) {
  for (r in recordnames){
    i[r] <- ifelse(is.null(i[r]), NA, i[r])
  }
  i <- i[recordnames]  # REORDER INNER VECTORS
  return(i)
})

# TWO LIST ARGUMENT SAPPLY
recordAttribs <- sapply(recordAttribs, function(i,r) {  
    if (is.null(i[r])) i[r] <- NA
        else i[r] <- i[r]         
    i <- i[recordnames]  # REORDER INNER VECTORS
    return(i)
}, recordnames)


df <- data.frame(t(recordAttribs))
```

Comment: thanks it worked perfectly for the test data I provided. When I went back and tried to apply it to the full data set I realized that there are some records with 9 columns not 7 ie `<Record type="HKQuantityTypeIdentifierFlightsClimbed" sourceName="Ryan Praskievicz iPhone" sourceVersion="9.3.2" device="&lt;&lt;HKDevice: 0x15a4af3f0&gt;, name:iPhone, manufacturer:Apple, model:iPhone, hardware:iPhone8,1, software:9.3.2&gt;" unit="count" creationDate="2016-06-02 12:27:46 -0400" startDate="2016-06-02 12:09:29 -0400" endDate="2016-06-02 12:09:29 -0400" value="1"/>` it did not work. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you know want to keep the common attributes or all? Do you know in advance what attributes to keep?

Comment: yeah I'd like to keep all 9 rows from the vector and just have NAs for the vectors with 7 rows.

Comment: See update, adjusting for any attributes that can be present or not of the 9.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is `xmlAttrsToDataFrame`, which should handle missing attributes. You can also get tags with a specific attribute like device

```
XML:::xmlAttrsToDataFrame(xml["//Record"])
XML:::xmlAttrsToDataFrame(xml["//Record[@device]"])
```